# Structured Templates in perl

Tags: perl, templates, nagios

I've been working on an nmap parser in perl, I've been going well with it, however I would like to write to a write to a file in a very structured manner. The file in question would be a nagios hosts.cfg (I'd use the nmap2nagios.pl on their wiki but it doesn't seem to be working and i'm having too much fun writing my own).

The file entries should look like this

```
define hosts {
       host_name      $host_name || $host_ip
       alias          $os
       address        $host_ip
       }
```

The above is just an example but I hope you get the idea. Any help will be appreciated! I've looked around for some template modules but they all seemed to be very geared towards cgi's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second Nick's suggestion. Some inspiration:

```
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process( \*DATA,
    {   ip    => '10.90.0.1',
        host  => 'some',
        alias => 'some_alias',
    } => 'file.cfg'
) or die $tt->error();

__DATA__
define hosts {
       host_name      [% host %]
       alias          [% alias %]
       address        [% ip %]
       }
```

**Note:** The Template refers to [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template%3a%3aToolkit)

Comment: I like the DATA handle, I'm going to steal it.

Answer (score 4):

I would always use [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) for outputting any structured document.  It's not specifically geared to CGI - I've used it happily to write config files for example.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the help. Never done this before and wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [formats](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). I never used it and the syntax looks insane but you don't need any modules.